# JCR Jackrabbit Versionising

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

Hi iam trying to restore a version of a node. But something goes wrong:

```
    Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("test1", "".toCharArray()));

    Workspace ws = session.getWorkspace();

    Node parentNode = session.getRootNode();

    //Create a first version
    Node n = parentNode.addNode("childNode", "nt:unstructured");
    n.addMixin("mix:versionable");
    n.setProperty("anyProperty", "Blah");
    session.save();
    Version firstVersion = ws.getVersionManager().checkin("/childNode");

    // add new version
    ws.getVersionManager().checkout("/childNode");
    n.setProperty("anyProperty", "Blah2");
    session.save();
    ws.getVersionManager().checkin("/childNode");


    // restoring old version
    ws.getVersionManager().restore("/childNode", firstVersion, true);
```

After that i get

```
javax.jcr.version.VersionException: VersionManager.restore(String, Version, boolean) not allowed on existing nodes; use VersionManager.restore(Version, boolean) instead: /childNode
```

Comment: By the looks of the API it looks like you're using the Sling `VersionManager`. Is that correct?

Comment: no it's "import javax.jcr.version.VersionManager;" with jackrabbit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the restore method call. If you look at the API docs you will see that the path (first argument) should not point to an existing node. If it does you will get this exception. Try with /childNode2 and it should restore it to that location.

From what it looks like:

```
ws.getVersionManager().restore(firstVersion, true);
```

should work and restore the previous version to the current location.

Comment: does this set the version of all nodes of the session to the version "firstVersion" or just the node which was checked in? And is my variable "n" updated automatically or have i to fetch a new one with session.getRootNode().getNode("/childNode"); Where can i find a detailed documentation about that?

Comment: What do you mean with 'all nodes'. It will only restore the firstVersion of the childNode. As far as I know you do not need to refresh the session, but I'm not 100% sure. More information can be found in the official JCR api http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Node.html